# Boxentriq Level 22

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

So I've been stuck on Boxentriq level 22 for a couple years now; put it away and picked it up more times than I can count. [image]There are musical tones in the background that reveal a binary code and in the image I see the word "inverto" in the music score. The hints say: focus on the binary code in the sound, the image contains a hint on what to do with the binary code, 1011 0111 1011 0000 0011 0111 1011, the answer is in another numeral system. I have tried flipping the 1s and 0s as well as reversing the whole string. I can't find any translation that makes sense.
[image]

Comment: I think you are not rot13(TENL) enough to solve this puzzle...